# How to select and replace the whole page with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

My design of a page forces me to refresh the whole page with html that I have loaded via ajax.

`$('html').replaceWith(data);`

Gives me errors. Any ideas?

Comment: Please post error and contents of data

Comment: Won't the html tag contain the script that is doing the replacing? If you're using the body tag make sure your html fits.

Answer (score 30):

I had the same issue, but this didn't help.
If you need to also replace the `<head>` tag (so, the whole page), you can also do

```
document.write(newPage);
```

Comment: I know this an old question, but for future references, this works, but you have to understand that it might leave the old DOM script handlers and result in memory leaks.

Comment: Thanks. It worked better than any other solution that I could come up with.

Answer (score 19):

Use body:

```
$('body').replaceWith(data);
```

Comment: Although this will not replace the head section, which might be required to load the necessary Javascript and CSS files necessary to render the page properly.

Comment: Actually, jQuery does do the work of execute any embedded javascript. CSS stylesheets will absolutely be applied. Just realize that the CSS stylesheets you've removed remain in the rulesets, they don't get removed.

Answer (score 13):

this might be the solution you'll require, **It replaces the entire document including its head**. You won't have any issues loading your new css, js & other resources. I've assumed you receive the new html content by invoking a REST api:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: form.attr('action'),
  data: form.serialize(), // serializes form elements
  success: function(response) {
    // re-writes the entire document
    var newDoc = document.open("text/html", "replace");
    newDoc.write(response);
    newDoc.close();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 10):

I had some issues with

```
$("body").replaceWith(newPage)
```

giving me some weird css problems, but this worked fine:

```
$("body").html(newPage);
```

Answer (score 2):

Strange behavior by jQuery.replaceWith and jQuery.html when executed with 'body' selector. You loose the body tag after the call:

```
$('body').replaceWith('<body>New body</body>');
```

It doesn't happen with any other selector as:

```
$('title').replaceWith('<title>New title</title>');
```

Also jQuery.html doesn't double the body tag (as it does with other tags), and operates like replaceWith when called like this:

```
$('body').html('<body>New body</body>');
```

I hope this isn't a grey zone of jQuery. Or if it is, they don't think to fix it. I have applications where I use $('body').html when $('body').replaceWith should be used.