# replace entire html

Tags: c#, html, dom, bho

I've got an external webservice that receives an entire html string parses its contents and modifies it before returning it to the browser.

Now inside the browser I simply need to **replace the html document with what I've received** but this is turning out to be an incredible **nightmare**!!!

I have tried all sort of combinations such as:

```
document.documentElement.outerHTML = responseText;
```

and

```
document.getElementsByTagName("html").item(0).innerHTML
```

and 
    document.getElementsByTagName("head").item(0).outterHTML

and nothing seems to work. it either **fails** with a COM exception (yes this is running inside a BHO or with some other random message saying that the O(o)utterHTML is not a valid property for the target.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can't. The closest is to replace the [body's inner html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793436/how-to-select-and-replace-the-whole-page-with-jquery).

Comment: But that's not enought! I need to replace the head too. And WHY on earth wouldn't this be possible??

Comment: Well, what would happen to the currently executing javascript? It's on the page?

Comment: That's the point... I don't care about the current page. I just wanna replace it. I'm doing exactly this in a ff extension and it all works as it should. The code that's doing the replacement is not js its managed C# code running as a BHO

Comment: Perhaps something along the lines of `document.open()`, write the contents, then replace the current document's location.

Comment: @MichaelItzoe I did not really understand your idea :p Could you show me please?

Comment: @Ricky I've never done this, but was just reading about it the other day (in a book, so no link; perhaps this'll help: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_open.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the webservice? If so you could use an HTML form on your side. To do that you need to make your server accept data encoded as either application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data.

If you can do that, you can simply put a form on your page with a single input in it. To get the new code from the webservice, write the HTML string to the inputs value and submit the form. The browser will automaticly display a returned HTML page.

If you can't/won't change the service then I agree with nonnb: I don't think it's possible to replace the entire HTML. But you can replace the innerHTML of the body and head manually. Split the body- and head-parts out of the returned string and replace them. It's basically the same as replacing the entire document, but you need to apply attributes to the body/head/html-tags manually, if needed.

Comment: The webservice and BHO should perform content modifications for all the pages a user might browse not just one.