# In express.js, res.render() is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I'm making a simple webapp with facebook login.

If the facebook login button on my page is clicked,

```
FB.api(
  '/me',
      'GET',
      {"fields":"id,name,birthday,gender"},
      function(response) {
        $.post('fb_login', response, "json");
      }
    );
```

is called, and a router handles '/fb_login' request; in the router the server checks the id of json object is already in its DB. If not, res.render('signup', ...) should be called.
However it didn't work. I already checked that res.render() was called, but the page 'signup.jade' didn't show up.

Here is my source code of router.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mysql = require('mysql');
var pool = mysql.createPool({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '1012'
});

/* GET home page. */
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
var userid = req.body.id;
if (userid) {
    pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        if (err) {
            console.error('DB Connection error!!');
            return;
        }
        console.log('DB Connection Success!!');
        connection.query('use vasket');
        connection.query('select count(*) result from user where userID=?', 
        [userid], function(err, result, field) {
            var isAlreadyUser = result[0].result;
            console.log(isAlreadyUser);
            if (isAlreadyUser == 1) {
                req.session.userid = userid;
                res.redirect('/');
                res.end();
                console.log('DB FB Login Success!!');
                connection.release();
            }
            else {
                connection.release();
                console.log('FIRST TIME!');
                //This method was called, but the page rendered didn't 
                res.render('signup', {id: req.body.id, name: req.body.name, birthday: req.body.birthday, gender: req.body.gender});
            }
        });
    });
} else {
    res.redirect('/');
    res.end();
}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: have you got any error ? are you sure req.body is set with id,name,...?

Comment: Try this first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15403791/in-express-js-app-render-vs-res-render-whats-the-difference There is a good elaboration

Comment: @Anonymous0day There is no error. I put json object in response at client, and the keys(id, name, ...) are correct.

Answer (score 0):

To help debugging maybe you can modify your code like that :

```js
// ... your code before

            else {
                connection.release();
                console.log('FIRST TIME!');


                console.log(req.body);


                //This method was called, but the page rendered didn't 
                res.render(
                  'signup', 
                  {
                    id      : req.body.id, 
                    name    : req.body.name, 
                    birthday: req.body.birthday, 
                    gender  : req.body.gender
                  } ,
                  function(err, html){
                    if(err) console.log(err);

                    console.log(html);                        
                    //res.send(html);
                    // trying same but forcing status
                    res.status(200).send(html);
                  }
                );
            }
        });
    });
} else {
    res.redirect('/');
    res.end();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. However, only `console.log(html)` worked, `res.send(html)` seems not working. The new view is not showing... What should I do?

Comment: try with forced status, i have updated my answer : `res.status(200).send(html);`

Answer (score 0):

This is an older question, but it's still in need of a solid answer. I had the exact same problem, but I think I've figured it out.

If the server's returning the proper response, that's not where your problem lies. jQuery (in the browser) will render the response, but *you have to tell it to do so*.

Here's what I had that was responding properly but not rendering:

```
$("#getsome").click(function() {
    $.get("/task/create");
});
```

And here's how I got it to render:

```
$("#getsome").click(function() {
    $.get("/task/create", function( data ) {
        document.write(data);
    });
});
```

Note that you may not need to replace the *entire* DOM like I'm doing.

References:

- [Replacing the entire
  DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793436/how-to-select-and-replace-the-whole-page-with-jquery)
- [jQuery.get](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)